If I do not declare move constructor, the copy one is called, but if I delete the move constructor - compilation error - why?
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    
    X(const X& src)
    {
        cout << "copy" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    
    X x2(move(x1));
}

Output:
copy
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    
    X(const X& src)
    {
        cout << "copy" << endl;
    }
    
    X(X&& src) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    X x1;

    X x2(move(x1));
}

Compilation error:
error: use of deleted function ‘X::X(X&&)’
   28 |     X x2(move(x1));
      |                  ^

So I am confused. When I did not write move constructor - looks like it did not generate one, because it called my copy constructor. But why then when I deleted the move one explicitly, it reported error?

When you declare a move-constructor, as default or delete, then you have declared a move-constructor and the compiler will use it. If it's deleted, then it can't be used and you will get an error. If you don't want move-semantics for your class, you should not declare it at all.

What is move, how is it declared?

@273K given cout I assume the OP is using using namespace std; so it would be std::move.

https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/10/17/equals-delete-means/

If you want to be 100% of what the move constructor does (or fallbacks to), I don't know any other option than defining it as X(X&& src)  : X(src) {} (delegated constructor). But this can have semantic implications because it will not be trivially movable, but I don't know a better way other than not declaring it and making sure (through tests) that moves really does a copy (which can be tricky, too).

Defining an overload as delete does not mean "this overload does not exist". It means "this overload exists, but attempting to call it is an error."
int foo(double) { return 1; }
// there is no foo(int) at all
int const x = foo(int(5)); // compiles fine: chooses foo(double) overload

int bar(double) { return 2; }
int bar(int) = delete;
int const y = bar(int(5)); // error! chose bar(int) over bar(double) but bar(int) = delete

If you don't declare a move constructor in a class but you do declare/define a copy constructor, then what you write is exactly what you get. Your first X's constructor has the two overloads X::X() and X::X(X const&), and that's it. You then call it with an X xvalue (that is, with an rvalue that refers to an existing object). Rvalues (including xvalues) can bind to const& references, so the X::X(X const&) overload is chosen in main and your code compiles fine.
If you add X::X(X&&) = delete;, again, what you write is what you get. X has a move constructor now (the overload X::(X&&) is declared), but calling it is an error. Rvalues prefer to bind to && references over const& references, so main now tries to call X::X(X&&) instead of X::X(const X&) and this fails.
(Sometimes, what you write is not what you get. Most importantly, if you write neither the copy nor move constructors nor assignments nor the destructor, then the compiler declares all 5. This enables the Rule of Zero: prefer to write classes that don't need custom special functions at all, where the compiler-generated ones are already correct.)

A link to further Rule of 3/5/0 reading would improve this answer.

Aha! deleted function is actually defined, but not allowed to be called. So AFAIU, if you provide one of: copy or move constructor, the compiler explicitly deletes the other one - makes sense (though when it deletes move constructor you will not realize it, as compiler will bind the copy one instead, so it is not nice of him). So there can be three options for "auto-generated" constructors/destructor/assignment operators: each can be generated as default, deleted or not generated at all. Now, you call foo(int) - if foo(int) is deleted - error, but if it doesn't exist foo(float) might work :)

@AndreyRubliov • ... the compiler explicitly deletes the other one...  Not quite.  The compiler does not implicitly synthesize the other one.

Note, by the way, that if you define a move constructor as = default;, or if the compiler implicitly declares one, and it turns out to be deleted, then it gets ignored during overload resolution, as if it didn't exist at all.
